# Not selecting what emacs ido is suggesting?

Tags: emacs, ido

In my current working directory `~/WD` there is a `abc.txt` file. Now I want to make another `abc.txt` under a sub directory `~/WD/NEW/`. As I type `C-x C-f` and the directory `~/WD/NEW/abc.txt`, ido is changing the string into `~/WD/abc.txt`, which is not what I want to open. As I try to modify the string back, ido automatically "correct" my input into the wrong string again.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using `ido` to open a file and you want to "step out" of `ido` in the middle of completing, you can use `C-f`. For example:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (`find-file`)

   ```
   Find file: ~/{ .emacs.d/ | bin/ | some-file.txt | tmp/ ... }
   ```
2. <kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> (narrow options with `ido`)

   ```
   Find file: ~/tmp/{ file1.txt | file2.txt | subdir/ }
   ```
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> ("step out" of `ido` mode)

   ```
   Find file: ~/tmp/
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of avoiding the completion proposed by `ido` is to validate your entry using <kbd>C-j</kbd> instead of <kbd>RET</kbd>

Example, in a case where file `foobar` already exists and you want to create file `foo`

1. <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> (`find-file`)

   ```
   Find file: ~/{.emacs.d | ... | foobar}
   ```
2. <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> (ido narrows options)

   ```
   Find file: ~/foo[foobar]
   ```
3. <kbd>C-j</kbd> (`ido-select-text`)

   This creates file `foo` instead of accepting `ido`'s `foobar` completion