# Emacs Completion refuse to create a new file

Tags: emacs, filenames, completion

When I try to create a new file in Emacs with C-x C-f, typing the file name, the Completion always automatically match the name. Unfortunately, once Emacs finds out there be no matched file, it will try to look for the file  with the name I just typed in other paths. So when there is a file with the same name in other path, I cannot create this file in the current path. Any one would tell me how to escape this annoying problem?

Comment: I suspect you're using either `ido` or `helm`. For the former, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007014/not-selecting-what-emacs-ido-is-suggesting/21008216).

Comment: @Chris: We shouldn't have to guess. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear, and so risks being closed. Try to give a step-by-step recipe of what you do, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file), to repro the problem.

By default (in vanilla Emacs), `C-x C-f` is bound to `find-file`, and it does *not* search multiple "paths". It looks only in the current directory (`default-directory`) unless you change the directory in the minibuffer during the command.

Start by using `C-h k C-x C-f`, to see what command you are actually using.

Comment: Completion feature always matches the file name I type in mini buffer.  For example there is a path /a and a file named test.txt and a subpath /a/b existed in it. Now I try to create a test.txt. Completion feature will automatically find the first file and refuse to create test.txt in /a/b.

Comment: Again, a **step-by-step** recipe, please, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: No completion features by `emacs -Q`, so the file is created normally. Thank you. But how to make a file with launching init file ?

Comment: As a advise from my friend, typing  'C-f' immediately after 'C-x C-f'  could void completion and create the new file. So I believe my problem be solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sounds like you're using Ido mode ("Interactive Do"). You should be aware of that, so you can ask Emacs for help about Ido mode when you have other trouble with it. Ido mode is not the default/ordinary way that Emacs does completion. See the Ido manual (`C-h i` and choose `Ido` in the menu).